# First jpa object filtering nested object inside model in repository function

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, model, spring-data-jpa

I have a model that is about a school classes lets say maths or geography. And in this model there is one object that gives list of Students. Students

So i want to find the first class that the students are in age of 18.

So in classes repository i want to have a function that gets the first class where students age is 18.

How can i write such query in jpa in repository?

I am trying to do something like:

```
@Query("SELECT MIN(tt.id) FROM class tt WHERE tt.Student=(SELECT st FROM Student st WHERE st.student.age= :age)")
```

Is this possible cause this query can not be calculated i get jpa exception that it can not be resolved

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

i can do what someone proposed but deleted the post , and it works use jpa normal function and write

```
public void findFirstByStudentsAge(Integer age);
```